# How to use foreach loop in mysql query

Tags: php, foreach

I want to add some condition to my sql select by using foreach loop. For example:

```
select id, custom_id, name, customer from db_clients where id = 5
```

By using foreach I want to and more "where" condition.

```
select id, custom_id, name, customer from db_clients where id = 5 and id = 19
```

My PHP code:

```
$this ='select id, custom_id, name, customer from db_clients where id = 5' . foreach($ids AS $id){
'. and id = '.$id}';
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: you can add another condition using AND is this what you mean?

Comment: I want "and" condition as many times as it is in the loop

Comment: i see now, cant you implode $ids in php first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this ='select id, custom_id, name, customer from db_clients where id in ('.implode(',',$ids).') ';
```

That does assume $ids always has at least one array value, it is can be empty you need to add another check before doing that or add a -1 or some id that will never exists into the array before populating it just to be sure it's never empty there's many ways to handle an empty situation.